# JMeter Report Generation Without Default saveservice

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Is there a way to generate a report from a .jtl file if I had set some saveservice values to false such as below:

jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message = false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false

Its complaining that it cant find them. I tried adding the column manually into the .jtl and just filling it with a null value but that didnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible given the [Results File Configuration properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) are the same.

So if you run your test on one machine and generating the results on another machine - make sure that the `jmeter.save.saveservice.` properties are **exactly the same**, this way you should be able to generate the dashboard normally.

So if you put the next lines to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
```

the dashboard generation will be successful.

Another option is [providing the properties via `-J` command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false -g -o /path/to/dashboard
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) article for more information on JMeter properties and ways of setting/overriding them.

The order of "columns" is defined under [CSVSaveService](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/save/CSVSaveService.java#L245) and as of JMeter 5.3 you cannot configure it, if you decide to save some metric it must be in particular column, i.e. `timeStamp` will always be the first, `elapsed` the second, etc.

Comment: That's what I thought. But even though I made sure the properties were exactly the same between the machine it was run on and where I was generating, it still wanted the responseMessage and failureMessage weirdly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out you can manually just enter the headers in the jtl/csv file and leave the column empty. As long as you have the necessary columns separated by commas and the saveservice deafult properties are included.

The headers need to be in the right order though as per a normal jtl results file. The headers dont seem to be able to be just added to the end.